# gwt-other way to access variables without converting gwt-module.html to jsp

Tags: gwt

gwt-other way to access variables without converting  gwt-module.html to jsp

I have to send data from one domain abc.com to other domain xyz.com where xyz.com is a gwt module.

1. I don't want to convert my gwt-module.html to jsp.
2. I don't want to add the variables as query params.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try using post messages, for communicating between cross domains
please go through the below link for example snippet:
 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: Thanks for quick response!! Will try it out